# $.ajax(): Origin null is not allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm just starting with `$.ajax()`. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Commons app</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if($) console.log('jQuery loaded!\n');

    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&ailimit=5&aifrom=Albert&aiprop=dimensions|mime&format=jsonfm&callback=?'
        })
        .done(function () { console.log('Yay!'); })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Error!'); })
        .always(function () { console.log('Complete!'); });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason I get the following error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allimages&gailimit=4&gaifrom=T&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&callback=?.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This method is deprecated from jQuery 1.9. Does not work anymore.

**Old answer:**

Try this (updated):

```
$.support.cors = true;

$(function () {
     $.ajax("http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allimages&gailimit=4&gaifrom=T&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&callback=?")
     .complete(function () { alert('complete'); })
     .error(function () { alert('error'); })
     .success(function (data) { alert(data); });
});
```

More about jQuery.support.cors setting here: [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)

P.S. thanks for a nice question! I believe it will be useful for me also in future.

Comment: I think this is not working anymore, just tested on Chrome for Mac, version 30.0.1599.101.
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allimages&gailimit=4&gaifrom=T&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&callback=?. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score -3):

You need to be aware of the cross-domain-restrictions for AJAX requests, which will prevent you from loading arbitrary websites in the background for safety reasons. See [here](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) for more information.

**Old Answer**:
When you use `$(foo)` you need to specify with `foo` which elements you mean to modify. What you probably are looking for is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // do something 
}
```

This will execute the functions once the document finished setting up its DOM structure.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. `$()` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't realize. :) Never seen that before. I added a second part to my answer. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Regarding your new answer: I don't think it's a cross-domain-restriction. The only other thing I'm doing is loading jQuery from Google's CDN.

Comment: I just found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin), which might help you.